# How do I connect a PS3 Controller with Xperia P?

Tags: sony-xperia-p

How do I connect a PS3 Controller with Xperia P?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your android is rooted  you can follow the steps

1. Install [Sixaxis Pairing tool](http://www.dancingpixelstudios.com/index.html) in your pc
2. Install [Sixaxis Controller app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dancingpixelstudios.sixaxiscontroller&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5kYW5jaW5ncGl4ZWxzdHVkaW9zLnNpeGF4aXNjb250cm9sbGVyIl0.) in your android
3. In android app Tap the `start` button and wait for bluetooth to initiate. If you
   get an 'Error: Missing required protocol' message, your device is
   not supported.
4. You must manually pair the controller with your
   phone. This can be done using `SixaxisPairTool` in yor pc.Your phones bluetooth
   address should be shown at the bottom of the main application window
   and will look something like 1A:3C:13:00:21:C2; you need to enter
   this number into the `SixaxisPairTool`
5. Once paired, unplug the USB cable and press the power button on the
   controller. If successful, the lights on the controller will stop
   blinking and a single light will remain on.
6. Tap the 'Change Input Method' button and select 'Sixaxis Controller'. You should now
   be able to use the controller in any games or applications that
   support key bindings, such as many emulators.

Source: http://www.dancingpixelstudios.com/sixaxiscontroller/instructions.html

Youtube video :

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WI3t-h390rc#t=22
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBcO_Gt0fd4